# How to remove top level domains (TLD) from domain names in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, url, count

How can I remove TLDs from a domain name in SQL dynamically? I have a column in my table containing the domain names of websites. Some domains have various extensions. Here is an example of rows:

```
Id  Domain
1   google.com
2   google.co.uk
3   google.de
4   google.fr
5   youtube.com
6   youtube.es
7   youtube.in
8   wordpress.com
9   wordpress.org
```

I want to count domain names ignoring TLDs. The result should be like this:

```
Name     Count
--------------
google     4
youtube    3
wordpress  2
```

And I don't know how to write a query to get that result.

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(Id) AS Count,
  ? AS Name
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ?
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

### Edit:

That domains have no protocol names like `https` and no `www` at the beginning.

Comment: You could take a look at the string functions available in SQL Server and see if they might help you form a solution. Of course ideally you wouldn't do this in SQL Server.

Comment: Could a domain have a sin domain? What would you expect, for example, for `meta.stackoverflow.com`, or `images.google.co.uk`?

Comment: Sub* domain (not sin, oops).

Comment: Yes, domains can have many subdomains, but in order to make this question easy to answer, I only expect extensions to be sliced. @Larnu

Comment: So what is an "extension"? ".com" isn't an "extension" it's a top level domain (TLD). For .co.uk the TLD is actually .uk, not .co.uk.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: ".co.uk" is a (two level) tld that you want to remove. you'll need a list of these.

Comment: OK, I edited the question title and body based on your comments. I replaced extension with TLD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is with `PARSENAME`:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    ,COALESCE(PARSENAME(Domain,3), PARSENAME(Domain,2)) AS domain 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY COALESCE(PARSENAME(Domain,3), PARSENAME(Domain,2))
ORDER BY [Count] DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it out.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Domain VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (Domain) VALUES
('google.com'),
('google.co.uk'),
('google.de'),
('google.fr'),
('youtube.com'),
('youtube.es'),
('youtube.in'),
('wordpress.com'),
('wordpress.org');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @dot CHAR(1) = '.';

SELECT LEFT(Domain, pos - 1) AS domain, COUNT(*) AS [Counter]
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(@dot, domain + @dot)) AS t(pos)
GROUP BY LEFT(Domain, pos - 1);
```

**Output**

| domain | Counter |
| --- | --- |
| google | 4 |
| wordpress | 2 |
| youtube | 3 |

Comment: I don't see how it combines google.co with google.

Comment: It is done via `LEFT()` function after we know position of the first dot.

Comment: It might fail where there's a subdomain in front, like: www.google.com. Although, OP didn't specify such urls in his question, and it might get hard because of co.uk domains for instance

Comment: It works for sample data but one comment suggests that for example op wants meta.stackoverflow.com to become meta.stackoverflow.